# How to stop/playback the video

Tags: ios

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4096, 768);


    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"F0" ofType:@"mov"];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback) 
                                          name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                          object:player];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [scrollView addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];

    UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"29-30-p1.jpg"]];
    image1.frame = CGRectMake(1024,0,1024,768);
    image1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:image1];
    image1.animationImages = eyeFrames;
    image1.animationDuration = 0.25;
    image1.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"29-30-p2.jpg"]];
    image2.frame = CGRectMake(2048,0,1024,768);
    image2.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:image2];

    UIImageView *image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"29-30-p3.jpg"]];
    image3.frame = CGRectMake(3072,0,1024,768);
    image3.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:image3];


    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *) aNotification{
     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player release];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    //NSLog(@"x=%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    [player stop];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [player play];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Guys, I have no idea why the `viewWillDisappear` and `viewWillAppear` loop is not working. I want to stop the video if I scroll and keep playing when I scroll back. Let me know why it is not working. Btw, I don't know why the program terminates when the video is finished. I have used same code in the previous project and showed no error. I get bit confused. Hope some1 can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

U gave `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4096, 768);` This means that the view will not disappear or appear when u scroll.The scroll will position wise disappear or appear.Actually scroll is on view.So U need to manupulate the video stop and play when u scroll.So,u give the frame for `player` and when the scroll moving position appears the player position then play it.and when crosses the player frame stop it.Do this play and stop code in `scrollViewDidScroll` method with if else condition.